# DRY duplicated code over multiple controllers

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a couple of nested routes under `/users/:user_id/...` with controllers which need the `user`. In all those controllers I have the following code. But I don't want to have the very same code in all those controllers but only in one place. Where is the right place to put it? How can I DRY it?

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.XyzController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller
  plug :assign_user

  [...]

  defp assign_user(conn, _opts) do
    case conn.params do
      %{"user_id" => user_id} ->
        case Repo.get(MyApp.User, user_id) do
          nil  -> invalid_user(conn)
          user -> assign(conn, :user, user)
        end
      _ -> invalid_user(conn)
    end
  end

  defp invalid_user(conn) do
    conn
    |> put_flash(:error, "Invalid user!")
    |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index))
    |> halt
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a Plug for this. I usually put it in `lib/plugs/` or `web/plugs/` with the file name being the same as the module's last section (e.g. `fetch_user.ex` for this Plug).

Something like (untested):

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Plugs.FetchUser do
  import Plug.Conn

  alias MyApp.Repo

  def init(_) do
    nil
  end

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    case conn.params do
      %{"user_id" => user_id} ->
        case Repo.get(MyApp.User, user_id) do
          nil  -> invalid_user(conn)
          user -> assign(conn, :user, user)
        end
      _ -> invalid_user(conn)
    end
  end

  defp invalid_user(conn) do
    conn
    |> put_flash(:error, "Invalid user!")
    |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index))
    |> halt
  end
end
```

and then in your controllers, write:

```
plug MyApp.Plugs.FetchUser
```